# Download Files From AWS S3 Without Access and Secret Keys in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a working code to download files from one of my buckets in S3 and does some conversion work through in Python. I **do not** embed the Access and Secret Keys in the code but **the keys are in** my AWS CLI configuration.

```
import boto3
import botocore


BUCKET_NAME = 'converted-parquet-bucket' # replace with your own bucket name
KEY = 'json-to-parquet/names.snappy.parquet' # replace with path and follow with key object

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

try:
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, 'names.snappy.parquet') #  replace the key object name
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e: # exception handling
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.") # if object that you are looking for does not exist it will print this
    else:
        raise

# Un comment lines 21 and 22 to convert csv to parquet
# dataframe = pandas.read_csv('names.csv')
# dataframe.to_parquet('names.snappy.parquet' ,engine='auto', compression='snappy')

data = pq.read_pandas('names.snappy.parquet', columns=['Year of Birth', 'Gender', 'Ethnicity', "Child's First Name", 'Count', 'Rank']).to_pandas()


#print(data) # this code will print the ALL the data in the parquet file

print(data.loc[data['Gender'] == 'MALE']) # this code will print the data in the parquet file ONLY what is in the query (SQL query)
```

Could someone help me how to get this code working **without** having access and secret keys embedded in the code **or** in AWS configure

Comment: You can just use a config file, import the keys from there, and access them that way.

Comment: @crookedleaf i do not want to use access & secret keys at all, that is the purpose of the question

Comment: ah... i thought you just didn't want to embed them in your code. in that case, i don't think there isn't anything you can do. if the files in the bucket are private and protected, then as far as i know you have to provide those keys to access them. similar to trying to access a site with a username and password but not wanting to provide a username and password

Comment: @crookedleaf yeah that is what am trying to do, i know the beginning of this question the answer might be no but i gave it a shot anyway just to see if its impossible or theres any workaround to it

Comment: Where do you intend to run this code? Your laptop, EC2, Lambda, somewhere else? And I presume that the S3 objects (the files themselves) are not publicly readable.

Comment: @jarmod im planning to run this code in my own laptop and later this code will be given to the client, but the clients do not want to use access and secret keys at all, whether it is hardcoded or configured through AWS CLI

Comment: S3 objects are either private or public. If they're private, then you cannot download them without credentials. Period. So, either your boto3 client has access to credentials (through IAM role on EC2 or environment or credentials file etc.) or it can get credentials (maybe it authenticates to a server which gives it credentials) or some process with credentials gives it pre-signed URLs to the objects (where the pre-signing itself requires credentials). You can't have security without authentication. Maybe you can explain more about why you think this should be possible without credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your function locally, you need to have your credentials on your local credentials/config file to interact with AWS resources.

One alternative would be to run on AWS Lambda (if your function runs periodically, you can set that up with CloudWatch Events) and use [Environment Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html) or [AWS Security Token Service (STS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) to generate temporary credentials.

Comment: Currently am using AWS CLI in my local and storing keys there, but what am trying to do is to not use AWS CLI at all and i dont want to hardcode the keys. I know it sounds weird but thats what my client is asking me to do

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use secret/access key, you should use *roles* and *policies*, then. Here's the deal:

Define a role (ex. `RoleWithAccess`) and be sure that your user (defined in your credentials) can assume this role

Set a *policy* for `RoleWithAccess`, giving read/write access to your buckets

If you are executing it in your local machine, run the necessary commands (AWS CLI) to create a *profile* that makes you assume `RoleWithAccess` (ex. `ProfileWithAccess`)

Execute your script using a *session* passing this *profile* as the argument, what means you need to replace:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
```

with

```
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='ProfileWithAccess')
s3 = session.resource('s3')
```

The upside of this approach is that if you are running it inside an EC2 instance, you can tie your instance to a specific role when you build it (ex. `RoleWithAccess`). In that case, you can completely ignore session, profile, all the AWS CLI *hocus pocus*, and just run `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')`.

You can also use AWS Lambda, setting a *role* and a *policy* with read/write permission to your bucket.

Comment: it still does not work for me because in your suggestion, CLI is still required and in my case, my client does not want to install CLI or hardcode Access and Secret keys.

Comment: You will not need the CLI or the keys if you run your code inside an EC2 instance, or a Lambda, just need to set your roles and policies.